# how to launch program out-side ros package from launch file

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are there any way to start a program in /usr/local/bin from launch file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10217/how-to-launch-program-out-side-ros-package-from-launch-file/) by [chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/510/chen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-06-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think there is a direct way to achieve this. But you could easily write a wrapper script and put it into a ros package. The script could look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec $1 ${@:2}
```

A corresponding launch entry, assuming that the script is called `launch_system_cmd.sh` and lies in package `mypackage`, would look like this:

```
<node name="shell_cmd" type="launch_system_cmd.sh" pkg="mypackage"
      args="/bin/echo foo" />
```

Please note that roslaunch will pass an additional parameter that sets the name for nodes and if necessary topic remappings. The output of the above command should be something like

```
foo __name:=shell_cmd
```

You might need to extend the wrapper script to get rid of those additional parameters.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2011-06-10**:
That would be one solution, does anybody knows another one? for instance, hidden tag in roslaunch?